# Question about UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: objective-c

I know some app have this function. When the user wait for the app culculating, a UIActivityIndicatorView is visible, and the whole screen is covered with a grey foreground.Any component in this view cannot be touched.
Someone know how to do this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello 
You can do I thing as when you make visible your indicator then make  setUserInteractionEnabled property  of view to NO and when the indicator get invisible set the property to YES i think this can solve your problem

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[indicator startAnimating];
```

when the indicator(activityindicator) gets invisible means

```
[indicator stopAnimating];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code from this page:[Activity Indicator by Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html)